# Rsolnp optimization error : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

Under R, I'm looking to solve following optimization problem :

```
The optimization problem i need to solve under R is :

Maximize the cost function detection_cost(x) subject to the following constraints:

W must be a probability distribution, i.e., sum(W) = 1 and 0 <= W_i <= 1 for all i = 1, ..., m.

The distances D_ij between the n sensors and the m sources must satisfy D_ij <= R for all j = 1, ..., n and i = 1, ..., m.

The distances D_ij between the n sensors and the m sources must satisfy D_ij > 0 for all j = 1, ..., n and i = 1, ..., m.

X and Y entries are binary values indicating which sensors are used and which sources are detected, respectively.

For any target i , any sensor j , D_ji <= R.

The sum of used sensors should not exceed n , i.e., sum(X) <= n
The sum of used targets should not exceed m , i.e., sum(Y) <= m

The cost function detection_cost(x) is a function of the optimization variables x, which include W, beta, Alpha, D, X, and Y, and is defined as:

detection_cost(x) = sum(Y*W*D_j)

where D_j is a vector of detection probabilities between all n sensors and each of m sources, computed using the logistic function:

D_j = 1 / (1 + exp(-beta_i *sum( Alpha_i * D_ji * X_j)))

where D_ji is the distance between the j-th sensor and the i-th source, X_j is a binary variable indicating whether the j-th sensor is used or not, and beta_i and Alpha_i are weights assigned to the i-th source.

Note that this is a non-convex optimization problem with nonlinear constraints, and must be solved using the L-BFGS-B method, which is a limited-memory quasi-Newton method for constrained optimization.
```

Then,i developed this code :

```
library(Rsolnp)

set.seed(123)
m <- 3  # number of sources
n <- 4  # number of sensors
D <- matrix(runif(m * n, 1, 10), nrow = m)  # initial distances from each sensor to each source
beta=runif(m,0,1)
Alpha=runif(n, 0, 1)
R=25

W <- runif(m, 0, 1)  # random weights of each source
W <- W / sum(W)  # normalize weights so that they sum to 1
Y <- rep(1, m)  # binary variables indicating which sources are detected
X=round(runif(n,0,1)) # binary variables indicating which sensors are used

param=list(W,beta,Alpha,D,X,Y)
x0 <- unlist(param)

detection_cost <- function(x) {

  W <- x[1:m]
  beta <- x[seq(m+1,2*m)]
  Alpha <- x[seq(2*m+1,2*m+n)]
  D <- t(matrix(x[seq(3*m+2,1+n*m+3*m)],ncol=m,nrow=n))
  Y=rev(x)[seq(1,m)]
  X=rev(x)[seq(m+1,m+n)]
  D_j=1 / (1 + exp(-beta * sum(Alpha * D * X) ))
  
  sum(Y*W*D_j)

}

#param=list(W,beta,Alpha,D,X,Y)
#x0 <- unlist(param)


# Define the constraints
constraints <- function(x) {
  
  # W must be a probability distribution
  
  #param=list(W,beta,Alpha,D,X,Y)
  
  eq1 <- sum(x[1:m]) - 1
  
  ineq1 <- x[1:m] - 0
  
  ineq2 <- x[1:m] - 1
  
  # The distances D_j between the n sensors and the m sources must satisfy D_j <= R
  
  ineq3 <- x[seq(3*m+2,1+n*m+3*m)] - R
  
  # The distances D_j between the n sensors and the m sources must satisfy D_j > 0
  
  ineq4 <- -x[seq(3*m+2,1+n*m+3*m)] 
  
  # For any target i, any sensor j, D_ji <= R
  
  ineq5 <- t(matrix(x0[seq(3*m+2,1+n*m+3*m)],ncol=m,nrow=n)) - R
  
  # The sum of used sensors should not exceed n
  
  ineq6 <- sum(rev(x)[seq(m+1,m+n)]) - n
  
  # The sum of used targets should not exceed m
  
  ineq7 <- sum(rev(x)[seq(1,m)]) - m
  
  return(list(eq1=eq1, ineq1=ineq1, ineq2=ineq2, ineq3=ineq3, ineq4=ineq4, ineq5=ineq5, ineq6=ineq6 , ineq7=ineq7))
}

# Set the initial values for the optimization variables

# param=list(W,beta,Alpha,D,X,Y)

lb <- c(rep(0, m), rep(-10, m) , rep(-10, n) , rep(0,n*m) , rep(0, m),rep(0, n))
ub <- c(rep(1, m), rep(10, m) , rep(10, n), rep(R,n*m), rep(1, m),rep(1, n) )

# Solve the optimization problem using the L-BFGS-B method
sol <- solnp(par=x0, fun=detection_cost, eqfun=constraints, LB=lb, UB=ub, control=list(trace=1))
```

I obtained this error :

```
Error in fun(pars, ...) - eqB : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(Rsolnp)

set.seed(123)
m <- 3  # number of sources
n <- 4  # number of sensors
D <- matrix(runif(m * n, 1, 10), nrow = m)  # initial distances from each sensor to each source
beta = runif(m, 0, 1)
Alpha = runif(n, 0, 1)
R = 25

W <- runif(m, 0, 1)  # random weights of each source
W <- W / sum(W)  # normalize weights so that they sum to 1
Y <- rep(1, m)  # binary variables indicating which sources are detected
X <- round(runif(n, 0, 1)) # binary variables indicating which sensors are used

param <- list(W, beta, Alpha, D, X, Y)
x0 <- unlist(list(D, X, Y))

x0 <- runif(19, 0, 25)

detection_cost <- function(x) {
  W <<- W
  beta <<- beta
  Alpha <<- Alpha
  D <- t(matrix(x[seq(1,m*n)],ncol=m,nrow=n))
  Y = rev(x)[seq(1,m)]
  X = rev(x)[seq(m+1,m+n)]
  D_j = 1 / (1 + exp(-beta * sum(Alpha * D * X) ))
  
  # Multiply the result by -1 to maximize
  -sum(Y*W*D_j)
}

# Define the constraints
constraints <- function(x) {
  ineq3 <- x[seq(1,m*n)] - R
  ineq4 <- x[seq(1,m*n)] 
  ineq6 <- sum(rev(x)[seq(m+1,m+n)]) - n
  ineq7 <- sum(rev(x)[seq(1,m)]) - m
  
  L1 <- list(ineq3=ineq3, ineq4=ineq4, ineq6=ineq6 , ineq7=ineq7)
  
  return(as.numeric(unlist(L1)))
}

lb <- c(rep(-R,n*m), rep(0, n), rep(0, m))
ub <- c(rep(R,n*m), rep(1, n), rep(1, m))

# Solve the optimization problem using the solnp method
sol <- solnp(par=x0, fun=detection_cost, eqfun=constraints, LB=lb, UB=ub, control=list(trace=1))
```

Comment: eqfun=constraints should be a numerical function ( return vector / error occured because it returned a list )